# PHP automatic import (use)

Tags: php

Is it possible to do an automatic import (As opposed to include) in a file?

So I include a file and it automatically does:

```
use \namespace\class;
```

For use in a simple templating system of sorts.

Comment: Sorry, but it is completely unclear what you ask. A wild guess here: you cannot somehow inject something into a file from the outside, if that is what you are thinking about, so the opposite of an inclusion. But as said: just a wild guess. Otherwise what is the issue? Certainly you can include a file and certainly that file can use the `use` command.

Comment: Simple answer, "No".... you have to explicitly specify your use namespaces, though you can specify several in a single statement

Comment: @MarkBaker Oh, you understood the question? Would you mind sharing?

Comment: Is this about autoloading? Or merely adding use statement? If the former, use composer. If the latter, a decent IDE can do it, e.g. phpstorm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right - **No.** You have to be explicit about classes that you use.

For example, imagine that you have 2 classes with the same name. How would system understand wich one to use?

Comment: Oh well. I was hoping to somehow force the include to inherit the scope/imports from the parent file but I suppose this will have to do.